# Design of RESTful endpoint for querying based on aggregate data

Tags: rest

Let's say we have two resources: Person, Movie.

```
persons/123
{id: 123, firstName: "John", lastName:"Travolta"}

persons/124
{id: 124, firstName: "Uma", lastName: "Thurman"}

persons/125
{id: 125, firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Saget"}

persons/126
{id: 126, firstName: "Christopher", lastName: "Walken"}

persons/127
{id: 127, firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Buscemi"}


movies/1
{id: 1, name: "Pulp Fiction"}

movies/2
{id:2, name: "Reservoir Dogs"}
```

Then, to relate the two, we have another resource: Cast Member

```
GET cast-members?movie.name=Pulp%20Fiction
[
    {
        id: 502,
        movie: {id: 1, name: "Pulp Fiction"}
        actor: {id: 123, firstName: "John", lastName:"Travolta"},
        character: "Vincent Vega"
    },
    {
        id: 503,
        movie: {id: 1, name: "Pulp Fiction"}
        actor: {id: 124, firstName: "Uma", lastName: "Thurman"},
        character: "Mia Wallace"
    },
    {
        id: 504,
        movie: {id: 1, name: "Pulp Fiction"}
        actor: {id: 126, firstName: "Christopher", lastName: "Walken"},
        character: "Buddy Holly"
    },
    ...
]
```

If I want to see all of the movies Christopher Walken has been in, I know I can do this:

```
GET cast-members?actor.id=125
```

What if I want to see all movies where *both* Uma Thurman and John Travolta are in the Cast? What does this endpoint look like?

```
GET cast-members?actor.id=124&actor.id=125
```

doesn't work.

We return Cast Members where actor.id was either 124 or 125?

```
[
    {
        id: 587,
        movie: {id: 10, name: "Kill Bill"}, 
        // John's not in this movie
        actor: {id: 124, firstName: "Uma", lastName: "Thurman"},        
        character: "The Bride"
    },
    {
        id: 597,
        movie: {id: 11, name: "Saturday Night Fever"}, 
        // Uma's not in this movie
        actor: {id: 123, firstName: "John", lastName:"Travolta"},
        character: "Tony Manero"
    },
    ...
]
```

This wouldn't be what we want, because we would have to join the movies on the client side (which isn't desirable since it means we have to page through a lot of data before being able to return a result).

the SQL query would be this:

```
SELECT Movie
FROM CastMember
WHERE Actor in (124, 125)
GROUP BY Movie
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Actor) = 2
```

Is there a way to translate this query to something that makes RESTful sense?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to pass an array of ids, similarly to when an HTML form has several fields with the same name; but I can't help you more on this, I guess others will come in with full answers

Comment: Why does using the same query parameter `actor.id` not work? What backend do you use?

Comment: @DisplayName if we pass two actors, we get either && or ||, yeah? So actor.id = 123 && actor.id = 124 returns nothing, actor.id = 123 || actor.id = 124 doesn't group by movie.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is the 'cast-members' resource - it's not clear that its modelling a real resource rather than some kind of 'synthetic' resource. Not all tables in a relational database are actually resources. ReSTful relationships are generally modeled as links between resources rather than as resources themselves.

The core of your resource breakdown here is that you've got

- movie
- person

and they're (perhaps) grouped into collections

- movies
- people

Let's say that you structure your URI space so that you've got

- /movie

  - a collection of movies
- /movie/{id}

  - an individual movie with a given id
- /person

  - a collection of people, possibly not all just actors in movies
- /person/{id}

  - an individual actor with a given id

If you want to find all the movies that a person was in, you search your movies resource based on an 'actor' query. That query could take multiple values, because it makes perfect sense to say that a given movie has more than one actor.

So, if you want to find all the films that persons with ids 1234 and 5678 were in your query should be

```
GET /movie?actor=1234,5678
```

Now, you could implement that in a few different ways depending on your use case. Perhaps it would only return a list of movie URIs and you'd have to query each one individually, but that doesn't sound great. Perhaps, on the other hand, it would return a list of all the full movie documents which match (titles, full cast, year, length, synopsis, reviews etc) - that could be a lot of data, so you might add a `page` parameter...

```
GET /movie?actor=1234,5678&page=2&pageSize=10
```

Perhaps you only want some of the details associated with each movie - you could add a parameter for the details which make sense for you....

```
GET  /movie?actor=1234,5678&details=title,id,cast
```

Note: so far there hasn't been need for a 'person' resource. However, the response document from your `movies` query will contain links to both individual movie URIs and person URIs...

```
movies?actor=12345,5678
[
 {
     movie: {id: 10, uri:"/movies/10", name: "...",
             cast: [{id: 12345, uri:"/people/12345", firstName: ... }
                    {id: 5678, uri:"/people/5678", firstName:...}
                    {...}
                   ]
     }
 },
 {
     movie: {id: 11, uri: "/movies/11", name: "...",
             cast: [{id: 12345, uri:"/people/12345", firstName: ... }
                    {id: 5678, uri:"/people/5678", firstName:...}
                    {...}
                   ]
     }
 },
    ...
]
```